# How to better position a texture on sides?

Tags: texturing, uv

Very often when I have to put a texture on something that is a cuboid, I always wonder how I should position the texture in the sides.

I wanted to create a wooden floor and what I did was to unwrap the mesh [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlnDU.png) using the option "project from view (bounds)", and as far I can see it doesn't look too fake [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYyHw.png). But is there a way to do better? How we should unwrap a mesh in order to look nice on the edges?

Thank you for the help

[image: (Picture of the unwrapping)]
[image: (how it looks on the borders]

Comment: Hello :). The words *look nice* and *improve* aren't very specific. Please rephrase the question to be more focused. For opinion-based art critique try [Blenderartists.org](https://blenderartists.org/). :)

Answer (score 0):

If it's a cubic shape like this, I personally don't bother using UVs (unless I have to export it somewhere else where nothing else works).

I instead use Generated texture coordinates, and I change the textures' projection from flat to box:

[image]

This way, the texture is projected from a box around the object, you can even use the "Blend" option to blend each face of the box so you don't see much seems:

[image]

Comment: Thank you seems much better! What if I have to export it in in Unity?

Comment: I think Unity has some ways to do that by itself. Otherwise, just use UVs, but maybe not like you did, I'd do something like these: https://i.imgur.com/j9ZNrnP.png   Don't forget to up vote and set this as your topic's answer in the top left corner.